# create .msi installation file for modern outlook web add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to create .msi installation file to load a modern outlook web add-in (not native) on your pc to avoid to ask the user to load the add-in manifest manually?

Answer (score 0):

Office web add-ins are not designed for deploying using MSI. Possible deployment options are described in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.

In a cloud deployment, to distribute your add-in to users in your organization by using the Microsoft 365 admin center. To distribute your add-in publicly to users you can publish it to the AppSource (add-ins' store).

Comment: I understand that office web add-ins are not designed for deploying using MSI but if I need to create it for some customer needs it would be possible?

Comment: Eugene's answer is correct. This isn't a supported scenario. In theory you may be able write an MSI to automatically do the steps in the article that Eugene linked, but there is no support for that.